# Is there a way to stream video in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Does react-native support video component(Officially, like without using any 3rd party libs)? I want to **stream/playback** a video from my cloud and looking for a way to integrate it to my **react-native** project.

Thanks in advance, any leads to the solution will be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you build your app using Expo (i.e. running the `create-react-native-app` command), then the Expo library includes a [video component](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/video/).

Here is a code sample:

```
<Video
  source={{ uri: 'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4' }}
  rate={1.0}
  volume={1.0}
  muted={false}
  resizeMode="cover"
  shouldPlay
  isLooping
  style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}
/>
```

I suppose Expo is technically a library. To my knowledge, there is no video library built into react-native.  You will need to use a package.

Comment: Hi can you please tell me What is the difference between **react-native-video** and **expo video**.i'm using react-native-video but it's not working for Android.thanks

Comment: broken link! Can you repost the link?

Comment: You cannot use this code for stream, It will first download the whole video and then play it like a normal video player

Answer (score 4):

If you are using react-native with native code(not using expo) : 
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video

```
<Video source={{uri: "background"}}   // Can be a URL or a local file.
   ref={(ref) => {
     this.player = ref
   }}                                      // Store reference
   onBuffer={this.onBuffer}                // Callback when remote video is buffering
   onError={this.videoError}               // Callback when video cannot be loaded
   style={styles.backgroundVideo} />
```

and also there is the  need to link the libraries

Comment: is react-native-video stream video when u use url or it will download video first ??

Comment: it streams the video

Comment: Do you have source that explain that it streams ? I can't find this

Comment: I need both features , streaming as well as downloading . can I use react-native-fetch-blob or rn-fetch-blob to download videos and use react-native-video for streaming. again I want to be sure if react-native-video streams the video or download whole video before play.

Answer (score -2):

You can use React Native Expo Video library like below

install this by running below command in to terminal

```
expo install expo-av
```

**API**

then import it like below,

```
import { Video } from 'expo-av';

<Video
  source={{ uri: 'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4' }}
  rate={1.0}
  volume={1.0}
  isMuted={false}
  resizeMode="cover"
  shouldPlay
  isLooping
  style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}
/>
```

in order to download/cache any video you can use Expo File System

install Expo File System Library

```
expo install expo-file-system
```

**API**

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

const callback = downloadProgress => {
  const progress = downloadProgress.totalBytesWritten / downloadProgress.totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
  this.setState({
    downloadProgress: progress,
  });
};

const downloadResumable = FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(
  'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4',
  FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'small.mp4',
  {},
  callback
);

try {
  const { uri } = await downloadResumable.downloadAsync();
  console.log('Finished downloading to ', uri);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

Comment: ,this is not a stream this code is basically a video player